# Ignoring "cin" and using "kbhit" to go to another function

Tags: c++, keyboard, event-handling

I need more help using C++,
Lets say that I dont know how old I am and I want to come back to "function2" pressing ESC.
I want something that when I press ESC (dont matters when) it ignores the "cin" and go to "function2".
(I know i don't need all libraries)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
# include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


int function2();
float a, c;

int main(){

do {
    while (kbhit()) 
    {c = getch();}

    if (c==27)
    {function2();}

    cout << "How old are you?\t" << c << endl;
    cin>>a;


    } while(c != 27);}


int function2(){
    cout<< "!!!END!!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: borland/watcom called, they want their kbhit() back!

Comment: @stefan: Not Borland specific, [`kbhit` (and `_kbhit`) is provided by the Microsoft C run-time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235390.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`conio.h` is a deprecated and non-standard C library. In order to get a character from the input you have to go through `cin` (like `cin.get()` for example), or use system-dependent functionality, in which case you'll need to look at the libraries provided with your compiler for your platform. Try `getch()` if it is available (another non portable function).

[At this site](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html) you can find several examples on how to implement what you need.

Answer (score 0):

conio.h does not provide any means of asynchronous I/O signaling. (More to the point, conio.h isn't even part of the C or C++ standards. I don't recommend trying to use it on Mac or Linux.) You would need to implement your own input system (basically rewrite `istream::operator >>` or the ludicrously-dangerous `gets`) to branch on special keys using `getch`. I recommend rethinking your input design, since even spawning a second thread to watch `GetKeyState` (I assume you're on Windows) with bated breath will not make it easy to interrupt a `getline` on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what has been mentioned with conio.h and the like, another problem with your original code is that you're testing floats against ints for instance

```
if (c==27)
```

Given that your input expects characters, you should be using a char (or integer) type (ignoring possible UTF-16 keyboard codes, which, given that you're on Windows, is likely).

For platform independent code, you perhaps want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int function2();
int c;
int main(){
  do {
    cin >> c;
    if (c == 27) {
      function2();
    }
    cout << "How old are you?" << endl;

  } while (c != 27);
  return 0;
}

int function2() {
  cout << "!!!END!!!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, there are issues with this approach - for proper event handling, you need to use functions GetKeyState, from within the WinAPI.